# How can you measure probability with a regression model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, confidence-interval

Classifier-based machine learning models have a corresponding "confidence" associated with each prediction. How can you get a confidence measure for a regression model?

Comment: Which classifier based machine learning methods have confidence associated with each prediction? By regression, do you mean linear regression or the prediction of a continuous outcome? The method will depend on which regression method you're using, and not all will have confidence intervals associated with individual predictions.

Comment: Confidence measure of what aspect of a regression model?